# Searching Picasa Web Albums with Firefox don't work

Tags: picasa

Every time I search there I end up in a loop, but it works for me if I use Chrome or IE.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you using "NoScript" in Firefox?

Comment: No Sir, I don't use NoScript. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reminds me of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/13852/impossible-to-reach-my-google-webmail-with-firefox).

Try clearing your cookies / cache in firefox and retrying. Seems like something has cached up wrong.

Comment: I tried this but with no success. :)

Comment: What you could do is clear out your FF settings using CCleaner. This may be even more thorough than FF's own clearing. http://www.ccleaner.com/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. :)
I just found out that it was a greasemonkey script that caused the problem.  (Google Un-safe Search to be exact)